# Integrate MATLAB code in Visual Studio 2010 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've seen that it is possible to call MATLAB functions from VS2010 (VC++).  I was wondering if it is possible to create executable files using VC++ that do not require any MATLAB software on the computer (like the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR))?

I would like to create a program written in VC++ that calls some of the MATLAB functions, but is completely standalone and can run from any Windows computer without the need of any prior MATLAB software to have been installed.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect to call Matlab's functions if there is no Matlab installed?

Comment: When I compile the VC++ project with the MATLAB functions, the MATLAB functions get compiled into C/C++ code, and then everything should work out.  The thing is, I don't think one can get VS2010 to compile MATLAB functions into C code, because then you'd probably be able to steal their code.

Comment: No, when you call Matlab functions from your c/c++ code, you do not compile Matlab source-code, but call functions from external libraries which interact with the Matlab runtime. (Maybe some code sample will make your question clearer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [is not possible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/163830) to install without MCR in any documented way and I even think that it is not legal.
However, there are some examples like [Imatest](http://www.imatest.com), who managed to do it in some of their earlier versions.

**Edit(1)**
 I almost forgot about [MatlabCoder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/). If you buy it, it can transform your `Matlab` code directly into `c` code. But it will not work with some of the toolboxes, like image processing.